# When is a String not a String

Tags: c#, oracle, sequence

From the "Things that go bump in the database engine" department:

This function returns what looks like a valid value, but the record is not posted (no err msg):

```
private String GetInterpreterTicketIDSequenceVal()
{
    con = new OracleConnection(oradb);
    con.Open();

    String query = "SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD-') || LTRIM(TO_CHAR(ABC.SOMETABLEID.NEXTVAL, '000000')) FROM DUAL";

    cmd = new OracleCommand(query, con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    //MessageBox.Show(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    return cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
```

...SEEMS to work (returns a value, and the insertion is (seemingly) made without squawking)... yet, no record is inserted into the database.

This kludgy (sp?) function, OTOH:

```
private String GetSomeTableIDSequenceVal_Fake()
{
    int iYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
    int iMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;
    int iDay = DateTime.Now.Day;
    int iHour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
    int iSecond = DateTime.Now.Second;

    String sYear = iYear.ToString();
    String sMonth = iMonth.ToString();
    String sDay = iDay.ToString();
    String sHour = iHour.ToString();
    String sSecond = iSecond.ToString();

    if (iMonth < 10)
    {
        sMonth = String.Format("0{0}", sMonth);
    }
    if (iDay < 10)
    {
        sDay = String.Format("0{0}", sDay);
    }
    if (iHour < 10)
    {
        sHour = String.Format("0{0}", sHour);
    }
    if (iSecond < 10)
    {
        sSecond = String.Format("0{0}", sSecond);
    }

    return String.Format("{0}{1}{2}-{3}{4}", sYear, sMonth, sDay, sHour, sSecond);
}
```

...works fine - the record is inserted into the database (the code that calls these functions follows).

It seems odd that they both return a string, yet one works, and one doesn't... that column doesn't have a constraint on it that is rejecting the value from the former function, so…???

Anyway, here’s the code that calls either of those functions, in context:

```
        try
        {
            con = new OracleConnection(oradb);
            con.Open();
            String query = "INSERT INTO ABC.SOMETABLE (TICKETID, TICKETSOURCE, ABOUTSOMEID, CATEGORYID, CONTACTEMAIL) VALUES (:p_TICKETID, :p_TICKETSOURCE, :p_ABOUTSOMEID, :p_CATEGORYID, :p_CONTACTEMAIL)";

            cmd = new OracleCommand(query, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            // Params = TICKETID, TICKETSOURCE, ABOUTSOMEID, CATEGORYID, CONTACTEMAIL
            OracleParameter p_TICKETID = new OracleParameter();
            p_TICKETID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            p_TICKETID.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2;
            p_TICKETID.Size = 20;
            // This doesn't allow the record to be inserted...???
            //p_TICKETID.Value = GetSomeTableIDSequenceVal();
            // ...but when I "fake it" below, the record IS inserted
            //p_TICKETID.Value = GetSomeTableIDSequenceVal_Fake();                cmd.Parameters.Add(p_TICKETID);

            OracleParameter p_TICKETSOURCE = new OracleParameter();
            p_TICKETSOURCE.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            p_TICKETSOURCE.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2;
            p_TICKETSOURCE.Size = 20;
            p_TICKETSOURCE.Value = textBoxTicketSource.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p_TICKETSOURCE);

            OracleParameter p_ABOUTSOMEID = new OracleParameter();
            p_ABOUTSOMEID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            p_ABOUTSOMEID.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32;
            p_ABOUTSOMEID.Value = textBoxAboutSOMEID.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p_ABOUTSOMEID);

            OracleParameter p_CATEGORYID = new OracleParameter();
            p_CATEGORYID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            p_CATEGORYID.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32;
            p_CATEGORYID.Value = textBoxCategoryID.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p_CATEGORYID);

            OracleParameter p_CONTACTEMAIL = new OracleParameter();
            p_CONTACTEMAIL.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            p_CONTACTEMAIL.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2;
            p_CONTACTEMAIL.Size = 100;
            p_CONTACTEMAIL.Value = textBoxContactEmail.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p_CONTACTEMAIL);

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (OracleException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Apparent success");
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
```

Update:

I added Xaction support, and it seems to make no difference whatsoever:

I encased it in a Transaction, and it makes no difference:

```
  OracleTransaction ot;
        . . .
        try
        {
            ot = con.BeginTransaction();
            cmd.Transaction = ot;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ot.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ot.Rollback();
        }
```

Update redux:

Luke made a good point about using two simultaneous connections; so, I changed that code to this:

```
private String GetInterpreterTicketIDSequenceVal()
{
    String query = "SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD-') || LTRIM(TO_CHAR(ABC.SOMETABLEID.NEXTVAL, '000000')) FROM DUAL";

    OracleCommand oc = new OracleCommand(query, con);
    oc.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    String s = oc.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    try
    {
        return s;
    }
    catch (OracleException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

...but still no joy in Mudville.

Update redux revisited:

I got it working; thanks everybody for your help and insight.

Actually, it had been working for awhile – my stupid query in Toad was the problem – I forgot that I was adding a slightly different value in new records than what I was querying for … so it looked like the records weren’t being added, but they really were.
tgif!

Comment: Have you tried to run the SELECT command in the SQLPLUS console?

Comment: Which string does `GetInterpreterTicketIDSequenceVal` return? Have you set a breakpoint to look what it returns?

Comment: Since the fake method supposedly makes this work, I'm guessing the posted code is just missing the code to add the p_TICKETID parameter to the parameters collection.  But that might have something to do with it.

Comment: Yes, I looked at the return values. The kludgy fake one is a value like 20120316-1557. the other one is similar, but not quite the same: things like 20120316-49109. The size of the VarChar in the table is 20, so it's not too large; and there is no constraint on that column, so...? Stepping through it, it does hit the ExecuteNonQuery just fine (doesn't drop out to the Rollback)...

Comment: @Corin: the only thing different in the code that calls these two methods (the "real" one that doesn't work and the "fake" one that does) is its call to either one method or the other (it's all included above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running your code above and I was only able to reproduce problems with it if the `INTERPRETERTICKETID` sequence had gone beyond 999999.  If you are having problems then there must be something that you are not telling us.  For example, how is your table `INTERPRETERTICKET` defined?  What constraints are on it?  How is the sequence defined?  Are there any triggers on the table?

Is there any need for your `GetInterpreterTicketIDSequenceVal()` method to use its own connection to the database?  Can it not just use the same connection that the rest of your code does?

If your sequence `INTERPRETERTICKETID` has gone beyond 999999 then the `TO_CHAR` call will return a string of hashes:

```
SQL> select ltrim(to_char(999999, '000000')) from dual;

LTRIM(T
-------
999999

SQL> select ltrim(to_char(1000000, '000000')) from dual;

LTRIM(T
-------
#######
```

I put a PK constraint on the `TICKETID` column and after running your code twice, I got a constraint violation error.

**EDIT**:

In response to your comment, it is possible to use a trigger to populate the `TICKETID` column.  You mentioned that your database apparently contains one such trigger, but without seeing how the trigger is defined, it's difficult to know what the problem with it could be.

I added the following trigger, and modified the C# code so that it didn't attempt to insert a value for TICKETID.  I ran the C# code a few times and it seemed to work.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INTERPRETERTICKETS_BI
  BEFORE INSERT ON INTERPRETERTICKETS
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD-') || LTRIM(TO_CHAR(INTERPRETERTICKETID.NEXTVAL, '000000'))
    INTO :new.TICKETID
    FROM DUAL;
END;
/
```

Comment: We don't have an "Identifier Ticket" table; assuming you mean INTERPRETERTICKETS.

The only constraint on the table is, indeed, for that column, but it looks harmless: Type = Primary Key; Status = Enabled; Deferrable = Not Deferrable; Deferred = Immediate; Validated = Validated

There is a Trigger that looks like it generates the value for that column automatically. This is actually what I expected would happen, and my first error trying to add a record was that that (PK) column was not being added... So, I added the value explicitly. Apparently you've got to do that with Oracle Sequences.

Comment: @ClayShannon: sorry for getting the table name wrong, I've fixed that now.  It is possible to use a trigger to generate the column value automatically; I've edited my answer to add details about how to do that.

Comment: I'm not at work now, and so don't have access to Toad/the database, but if the Trigger is auto-adding that val (makes sense that they would design it that way), why does it work fine with my "fake" function? Something's rotten in den Mark.

Comment: @ClayShannon: perhaps the trigger doesn't generate a value for the column automatically?  Perhaps it's disabled?  Without seeing the code of the trigger I cannot say.

Answer (score 1):

the way you setup the parameters seems very strange since your parameter object end up without a name - try changing your code similar to this:

```
OracleParameter p_TICKETID = new OracleParameter("p_TICKETID", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
p_TICKETID.Size = 20;
```

Comment: I changed my code to that style, and no change; I think the reason I don't need the params to be explicitly named is that as long as they are added in the same order they appear in the query statement, they'll work.

Comment: I got it working; thanks everybody for your help and insight.

 

Actually, it had been working for awhile – my stupid query in Toad was the problem – I forgot that I was adding a slightly different value in new records than what I was searching on…so it looked like the records weren’t being added, but they really were.